# Haskell DLL causes memory leak

Tags: haskell, dll, memory-leaks, ghc, ffi

I am working on a C++ project that uses a Haskell DLL (GHC version is 8.0.1 x64). I've noticed, that the executing program consumes much memory. I investigated into the matter and that's what I've found out. Let's consider the following minimal example. Here is a little project that consists of three files.

**HaskellExports.hs**

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module HaskellExports where

import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.StablePtr

foreign export ccall foo :: CInt -> IO (StablePtr Int)

foo :: CInt -> IO (StablePtr Int)
foo (CInt n) = newStablePtr (fromIntegral n)
```

Contains a function that is supposed to be called from a C/C++ code.

**CWrapper.cpp**

```cpp
#define DLLExport extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 

DLLExport void* c_smth (const int num)
{
    return 0;
}
```

I intentionally didn't include the real exports of the Haskell functions, because they make no difference to this example.

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        HINSTANCE module = ::LoadLibrary(L"HaskellExports.dll");
        ::FreeLibrary(module);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here, in an endless loop, I load the library and free it at once. Let's try to build the DLL in two different ways. First, let's not include the Haskell object file:

```sh
ghc -c HaskellExports.hs
ghc -c CWrapper.cpp 
ghc -shared -no-hs-main -o HaskellExports.dll CWrapper.o
```

I've run the program and noticed (with the help of Windows process monitor), that the memory resources are captured and released properly.

Now let's also add the Haskell object file:

```sh
ghc -c HaskellExports.hs
ghc -c CWrapper.cpp 
ghc -shared -no-hs-main -o HaskellExports.dll CWrapper.o HaskellExports.o
```

I've run the program again and noticed, that it consumes more and more memory in length of time with no intention to release it. This situation leads to a crash.

What am I doing wrong?

**P.S.** Further investigation showed that memory leak is caused only when `HaskellExport.hs` contains at least one `foreign export` function.

Comment: Interesting, but I wonder: why do you need to load a dynamic library over and over again?

Comment: Isn't it necessary to do a call to `hs_init` to initialise the runtime system?

Comment: @mschmidt Yeah, it is necessary if you are going to use the library. But I tried to make the most minimal example: it means that whether you call `hs_init` or not, the consuming memory behavior is the same.

Comment: @leftaroundabout In the project I work on it is needed due to some architectural reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to send an e-mail to ghc-devs mailing list. (To read all correspondence, see [the question](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/ghc-devs/2018-August/016170.html) and further messages, the answer can be found [here](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/ghc-devs/2018-August/016173.html)).

The brief explanation. The memory leak is caused due to the following: for each foreign export RTS creates a static C wrapper, which is initialized on `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`, but it has no finalizer/destructor to be called during `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`. So it will stay alive till the program termination.